# command line arguements not recognised by int _tmain ( int argc, TCHAR* argv[] ) with unicode defined

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, mingw

```
#define UNICODE
#define WINVER 0x502
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR* argv[] ) {

    if ( argc > 1 && lstrcmpi( argv[1], L"install" ) == 0 ) {
        printf ( "In install\n");
    }
    else if ( argc > 1 && lstrcmpi( argv[1], L"uninstall" ) == 0 ) {
        printf ( "In Uninstall\n" );
    }
    else if ( argc > 1 && lstrcmpi( argv[1], L"start" ) == 0 ) {
        printf ( "In Start\n" );
    }
    else {
        printf ( "In else part\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code doesnt detect the command line arguements and always prints the "else" part.
How to achieve what I intend to??

Am using "MINGW".. In windows XP..

thanks..

Comment: Diagnose the problem by printing `argv[1]`

Comment: Also, why are you using `TCHAR`? That's rather pointless, not least because your code only works with wide chars. Don't make life hard for yourself and use `wchar_t` instead of `TCHAR`. `TCHAR` was what you used when you needed you code to run on Windows 98.

Comment: If you google for "mingw wmain", you will find a fair bit of information related to this.  It seems that, perhaps, Unicode input parameters are not yet fully available.  Although, I saw one recent bit of info on github that implied you could use a -municode parameter ... but it wasn't supported with the version of mingw that I have installed.

Comment: with out unicode defined the above code works fine.

Comment: "with out unicode defined the above code works fine." How can it? `lstrcmpi` takes wide string parameters. Did you try to print `argv[1]` to see what it contains.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are thinking of `lstrcmpiW()`. `lstrcmpi()`, on the other hand, takes `TCHAR*` parameters instead.  When `UNICODE` is not defined, both `TCHAR` and `lstrcmpi()` use Ansi.

Comment: @remy it will still fail when unicode is not defined because the second parameter being passed is a wide string

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: easily remedied by replacing the `L` prefix with the `TEXT()` macro instead. Then the string literal will be narrow or wide based on the `UNICODE` define, just as `lstrcmpi()` is.

Comment: @remy Well yes. My point was more the contradiction in the question/comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think MINGW compiler dont define wmain altough UNICODE is defined. In your checking code use rather CommandLineToArgvW.

Ps: sorry for my English :-)